# Make flag notifications appear without having to reload the page

Tags: feature-request, flags, notifications, moderator-tools

As a moderator on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), I always have the [Newest Questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) page open, and can see new questions appear in real-time, which is super cool. Each time a new question is posted, my browser tab changes color, and I can click on the "*1 question with new activity*" grey rectangle to reveal it. 30% of the time, the question looks odd and I open it in a new tab to check it further. If there is any flag I can see it in this new tab.

PROBLEM: The remaining 70% of the time, I just go back to my real-life activities, and **miss an opportunity to see new flags** because I did not reload the page nor load a new page.

If new questions appear in real-time, what arguments are there against showing new flags too?

[image]

---

Different but related questions:

- [Make flag counts for moderators visible on other SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149348/make-flag-counts-for-moderators-visible-on-other-se-sites) - The answers there say that you should relax, for instance not care about SR moderation when busy on SO. My case here is different: I check the "Newest questions" page precisely when I am in the mood to do SR moderation.
- [Poll in background for StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ inbox events and update the titlebar accordingly à la Facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66712/poll-in-background-for-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-inbox-events) - Not about moderation

Comment: I'd like to see this too - notifications are pushed to clients over websockets, so surely flags can be too.