# Are Stack Exchange employees notified of all spam flags across the network?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools, spam, stack-exchange-team

Several hours ago a [very low quality answer on Science Fiction and Fantasy was deleted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/142704/31936) by a Stack Exchange employee.

I'm only a moderator on one site, but [it is my understanding that moderator flags are only shown on the current site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149348/299342) even if a user is a moderator on multiple sites (such as SE employees). However, the employee who deleted the linked answer isn't active on SFF and has handled only a few flags on SFF for all time, so it seems unlikely that he happened to visit SFF and see that post in the flag queue. The only thing which seems notable about the flagged post is that it had received two spam flags.

That leads me to suspect that SE employees are notified of spam flags anywhere on the network (e.g. an employee browsing SO would see a spam flag on a different site, like SFF). Is that the case? Or is it just a coincidence that an SE employee who isn't active on SFF happened to visit SFF and see that flag?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question OP posted a question here on Meta (now deleted), linking to that question.

I went through, saw the bad answer (with flags and downvotes) and deleted it.